# usb km/kvm switch with zero latency switching between devices

Tags: raspberry-pi, kvm

A standard usb km (or kvm) switch will only expose the kb/m to one output device at a time, so switching to another device takes 5-10 seconds as the device detects the kb/m and installs the drivers (makes me miss the days of ps/2).  Is there a km/kvm switch (with hotkey support) that has a software layer that will identify as a generic kb/m on all outputs at all times, so that switching to a different output will only internally route the kb/m events to the proper output driver, and not need the OS to re-detect the device?

If the solution does not exist at a reasonable price, I am not averse to deploying a Rpi as an OTG device if a project exists that does what I'm asking above (all outputs active, taking the HID kb/m input and routing it to the desired output) with no appreciable input latency.

Answer (score 4):

There is a special class of KVM switch called DDM-class KVM switch that has a built-in DDM (Dynamic Device Mapping) core technology to keep all the shared HID devices of the KVM switch feeding to all connected systems of the KVM switch. So, all connected systems of the DDM-class KVM switch will not detect unplug of shared keyboard mouse even the target system of the keyboard mouse is not selected.